# Should a PHP endpoint return an image using 'readfile' or 'base64_encode'?

Tags: php, ajax, image, base64

I'm working on an endpoint that returns a single image from the filesystem (like a user portrait). I use an ajax script for testing that processes the result of an endpoint and sticks it in a div. This raised the issue of constructing an image from an ajax response blob. The solutions I found on SO all assume that the image is being returned in base64 encoding. I got it working by changing the endpoint to output the image with base64 encoding, but this seems like an extra step, especially for iOS clients, which can understand the image being output by `readfile`.

Is this what people do in production environments? Doesn't conversion to base64 increase the size and put a load on the server? What advantages/disadvantages are there to each method? Is there another way that is even better?

```
header("Content-type: {$imginfo['mime']}");

// Output the file stream
readfile($filename);

// Output as base64
$type = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
base64_encode($data);
echo base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: _"Is this what people do in production environments?"_ - Different application have different requirements. You get to decide this yourself. Do what makes sense for you and your application. And yes, if you base64 encode content, the response will be larger.

Comment: I would not use base64 in this case but that's really just my opinion. See [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) for creating a usable URI from binary (blob) data